# Does jquery's $.get(...) ajax success function trigger when the file has completed downloading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, loading

Basically I want to know if the 'success function' of jQuery's $.get() method is fired when the whole file has finished downloading. I suspect it is, but just want to make sure.

I'm using a series of $.get() requests to load files of a page (CSS, javascript, etc) while I display a 'loading screen'.

On each success callback of the request, I load the next file until finally they're all finished, and I remove my loading screen.

The issue is that randomly, usually on slow connections (site is designed for mobile browsing) the loading screen will disappear but the CSS for the site has not been applied until ~1-2 seconds later so the user will see a non-styled site briefly before the CSS is applied to buttons, etc.

Here is the code I'm using to loading my resources

```
if(!window.MyResourceLoader) window.MyResourceLoader = {};

// list of resources to load
MyResourceLoader.MyResources = new Array(
  "include/resources/.....css",
  "include/resources/.....css",
  "include/modules/.......js",
  "include/...............js",
  "include/...............js");

// reverse the array so we load it in the order above
MyResourceLoader.MyResources.reverse();

MyResourceLoader.resourcesToLoad = MyResourceLoader.MyResources.length;

/**
 * Recursive function - loads the resources
 */
MyResourceLoader.loadMyResources = function()
{
  // exit condition - stop recurring if we've run out of resources to load
  if(this.MyResources.length < 1)
  {
    $(".meter > span").each(function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({
          width: "100%"
        }, 300);
    });
    return;
  }

  // get the next resource to load
  var resource = this.MyResources.pop();

  // if the resource is a css file, append it to the head
  if(resource.match(/css$/))
  {
    // append timestamp to resource
    resource += ("?" + new Date().getTime());

    // ie support
    if(document.createStyleSheet)
      document.createStyleSheet(resource);
    else
      $("head").append($('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="' + resource + '">'));

    // recusivley load resources
    this.loadMyResources();
  }
  else if(resource.match(/\.js$/))
  {
    // append timestamp to resource
    resource += ("?" + new Date().getTime());

    // if the resource is a js file, make a request for it
    $.get(resource, function()
    {
      // on successful request of the file, make another call to load resource
      MyResourceLoader.loadMyResources();
    });
  }
}
```

The final javascript file is a 'load end' .js file that does the following:

```
// fade out the loading screen
$('#webapp-loader').css('opacity',0);
setTimeout(function()
{
  $('#webapp-loader').remove();
}, 1000);
```

So as you can see, there is even a 1 second buffer at the end of the loading before it removes the loading screen.

Comment: Just re-read the code and I think I found my issue :) - The resource loading is only appending the CSS file to the head of the document, which triggers the download of the CSS file - so the above code will not wait for the CSS in the head to finish downloading before it thinks it is 'done loading'

Answer (score 0):

Yes $.get() downloads the whole file, as I commented above my issue here was that the resource loading is only appending the CSS file to the head of the document, which triggers the download of the CSS file - so the above code will not wait for the CSS in the head to finish downloading before it thinks it is 'done loading'

Answer (score 0):

When loading resources by appending them into the DOM, they don't get loaded immediately. You have to listen for the `onload` to know if the element has loaded its contents. The problem is, [unlike the `script` tag which has an almost reliable `onload` and `onerror`, the `link` tag doesn't](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/load.html). you can't check if the stylesheet has loaded.

I suggest you load the CSS via AJAX so you have a sense of when the CSS is loaded. You then put the returned CSS into a style tag in the page. As for JS, since you are using jQuery, you can use [`getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

Also, you can load them all at once, in parallel. That way, you'll load them faster. To keep track of them, you can use the promises each jQuery ajax function returns. You can then use [`when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to check when all promises have their resources loaded already.

Also, you may have over-complicated your approach. Here's a shorter one:

```
//the resource list
var resources = [
  'include/resources/.....css',
  'include/resources/.....css',
  'include/modules/.......js',
  'include/...............js',
  'include/...............js'
];

//collection of promises to listen
var promises = [];
var timestamp = '?' + new Date().getTime();
var current, ext, promise;

//load each resource
for(var i = 0; i < resources.length; ++i){

  current = resources[i];

  //RegExp-less extension extraction (assuming they end with extensions)
  ext = current.substr(current.lastIndexOf('.')+1).toLowerCase();

  //extension check
  if(ext === 'css'){
    promise = $.get(current + timestamp).done(function(css){
      //when the CSS AJAX finishes, append
      $('<style>').html(css).appendTo('head');
    });
  } else if(ext === 'js'){
    promise = $.getScript(current + timestamp);
  }

  //push the promise
  promises.push(promise);
}

//listen with all are done
$.when.apply(null,promises).done(function(){
  //all done!
});
```